# issues to use stringstream to parse ifstream

Tags: c++

I have a txt file which content is as follows:

```
1
256 128
32768
```

I wrote a code to parse these numbers. But after `ss << line2;`, the variable `ss` is empty. Does anyone help me on this issue ?

```
ifstream fr;
fr.open(input);
if (!fr)
    return false;
string line1;
string line2;
getline(fr, line1);
getline(fr, line1);
getline(fr, line2);
stringstream ss;
uint32_t width, height;
ss << line1;
ss >> width >> height;
ss.str(string());
ss << line2; // After this line, why does `ss` is empty instead of holding `32768` ? 
fr.close();
```

FYI: [image]

Comment: Why do you call `ss.str(string());`?

Comment: @Thomas presumably to clear the `stringstream` in case anything else was in the file that wasn't meant to be read in.

Comment: @scohe001 It should be empty after `ss >> width >> height;`

Comment: @Thomas unless the file is in a bad format and there's more on that line. Or maybe the file format is such that anything after the first two numbers on that line is considered a comment. Who's to say?

Comment: You need a `ss.clear`. `ss.good()` returns `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You need to call `clear()`

After you read in `ss >> width >> height;`, you've read everything in the stringstream, so `eofbit` is set and the `failbit` is flipped.

After you fill the stringstream again, you need to flip the `failbit` back to false, to let the stream know it's good to be read from/written to again:

```
ss.str(string());
ss.clear(); // Let the world know we're good again!
ss << line2; // ss.str() will now show that we have stuff!
```